# onload or addEventListener on new Image() canvas doesn't work

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem when I load local (or online) images. So I use canvas HTML 5 then I put a new image on it but image never load at first time. I need to refresh page one time. The first time, images are loaded but not in good time so there are not showed. Then,, when I refresh, images are still in caches of my browser (firefox 50) so that's work.
I saw on forum that I need to wait with :

```
myimage.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(myimage,0,0,myimage_size,myimage_size);
}
myimage.src = mysrc;
```

But this doesn't work, images are not showed. So I try another way with that:

```
var elementHTML = document.createElement('img');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = my_size;
    canvas.height = my_size;
    elementHTML.appendChild(canvas);
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    base_image = new Image();   
    base_image.src = base_image_src;    
    base_image.addEventListener('load', test(this.owner));

    function test(owner){
//here there is the trick, with that, all work but I need program work without that !
        while(window.alert("done")){};
        context.drawImage(base_image,0,0,my_size,my_size)

        if (owner == "1") {
//I modified some colors of my image    
        recolorRGBImage(context,lineTuleColorRGB,playerLineTuleColorRGB_1,lineTrigger);
            recolorRGBImage(context,fillTuleColorRGB,playerFillTuleColorRGB_1,fillTrigger);
        }
        else {
            recolorRGBImage(context,lineTuleColorRGB,playerLineTuleColorRGB_2,lineTrigger);
            recolorRGBImage(context,fillTuleColorRGB,playerFillTuleColorRGB_2,fillTrigger);
        }
    }
```

That's work but obviously, alerts must never show. How can I do what I did without alert? (Alert used like onload because these methods doesn't work)

Thanks !

Comment: Your second version is attaching `undefined` (the return value of `test`) as event handler, what you want is `var owner = this.owner; base_image.addEventListener('load', function(evt){test(owner)})` Not sure what doesn't work in your first one though. I guess you omitted something in your code blocks. Add `myimage.onerror = e => console.log(e);` just in case.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, the owner things is just because inside the function my this.owner is out of scope so I put it in, as I said this version works as I want so no problem about it.

The console print nothing when I add myimage.onerror (I put before myimage.onload).

Comment: If you wish to keep the current referance of `this` use the function method `Function,bind` eg `image.addEventListener('load', test.bind(this))` and in the function `this` will reference the `this` that you bound to the function

Comment: That's not solve my problem but thanks for the trick !